Element-wise function that preserves matrix rank?
Let's say you have a matrix $\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ with rank $r$, for example, this $2 \times 2$ matrix:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$$
You apply a function $F(x)$ to this matrix element-wise:
$$\tilde{A} = \begin{bmatrix} F(a) & F(b) \\\ F(c) & F(d)  \end{bmatrix}$$
What must be true about the element-wise function $F(x)$ such that it preserves the matrix rank, i.e. $rank(A) = rank(\tilde{A})$?
My intuition tells me that if $F(x)$ is a monotonically increasing/decreasing function, it will preserve matrix rank. However, I'm not sure how I can prove this. Additionally, I don't know if a more general condition exists.

Why not rather write your example in the case $r=2$ (easier to write and read)? As for your inuition, it is wrong, even for $r=1$. About your general problem: I don't think such a function exists, except multiplication by a non-zero constant.

Even a simple translation (adding 1 unit) fails on $$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$$

Hi @AnneBauval I have updated the case from $r=4$ to $r=2$ per your suggestion, thanks.

I wonder if "multiplication by a non-zero constant" would still work if it only applied to a single column/row?

Multiplying a column by a nonzero constant, and adding a multiple of a different column to it, are operations that preserve the dimension of the space spanned by the columns.

Edit: answer modified substantially after justified criticism from OP.
We start by supposing $n\geq2,$ noting that in dimension $n=1$ a necessary and sufficient condition is for $F$ to map 0 to 0 and to map nonzero numbers to nonzero numbers.
Let $n\geq2$ and suppose that $F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ preserves the rank of every $n\times n$ matrix when applied to individual entries. Then it must transform singular $2\times2$ submatrices into singular matrices and we have, for all real $a,$ $b$ and $c$:
$$F(a)F(bc)-F(ac)F(b)=0.$$
$F(1)$ cannot be zero; otherwise for all $a,$ putting $c=a$ and $b=1$:
$$F(a)F(a)=F(a^2)F(1)=0$$
and then $F$ would be identically 0, which does not preserve rank.
This means that for all real $a$ and $b$:
$$F(ab)=\frac{F(a)F(b)}{F(1)}.$$
Thus the function
$$g:\mathbb R_0\to\mathbb R_0:x\mapsto \frac{F(x)}{F(1)}$$
is an automorphism of the multiplicative group of nonzero real numbers.
In two dimensions this is also a sufficient condition: if $g$ is an automorphism of the nonzero reals and $c$ is an arbitrary nonzero real, then the function $F=c.g$ extended to all of $\mathbb R$ by $F(0)=0$, when applied to the individual elements of a square matrix, preserves the zero or nonzero nature of the determinant.
The multiplicative group of nonzero reals is a direct product of $\mathbb Z_2=\{-1,1\}$ with the multiplicative group of positive reals. The first component can be absorbed into the sign of the constant $c.$ The second component is isomorphic, via the logarithm, with the additive group $(\mathbb R,+).$ The automorphism group of the latter is uncountably large and involves a basis of $\mathbb R$ as a vector space over the rationals $\mathbb Q.$
If we restrict ourselves to continuous $F$ then the automorphisms become more tractable and we get
$$F(x)=c.\hbox{sgn}(x)|x|^r$$
for arbitrary nonzero real constants $c$ and $r$. The absolute value is the canonical projection homomorphism of $(\mathbb R_0,*)$ onto $\mathbb R_0/\{-1,1\}\cong\mathbb R^+_0.$ The sign function is the projection onto $\mathbb R_0/\mathbb R_0^+\cong\{-1,1\}.$
In higher dimensions $n\geq3$ we have additional conditions imposed by the higher-order determinants. Applying this to the singular $3\times3$ matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & a+b \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
we get $F(a+b)=F(a)+F(b),$ where we have used $F(0)=0$ and $F(1)\neq0.$ This says that $g$ is also a homomorphism of the additive group of reals. Taken together $g$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb R$ as a field, and that can only be the identity (automorphisms of $\mathbb R$ map squares to squares, and that characterizes the positive numbers, so automorphisms must be order-preserving).
Therefore in dimensions 3 and higher there is no need to impose additional continuity restrictions and the only $F$ satisfying the condition is multiplication by a nonzero constant.
If we replace $\mathbb R$ with a more general field, the necessary and sufficient condition in dimensions $n\geq3$ remains for $F$ to be a nonzero constant multiple of a field automorphism. The condition is sufficient because any determinant of a square submatrix is a homogeneous polynomial in the matrix entries, and applying (a nonzero constant times) a field automorphism to the individual entries preserves the zero/nonzero character of such a polynomial. A nontrivial example is complex conjugation.

Thanks @Lieven. Can you help explain this part further: "If this is true for arbitrary $a, b$ and $x$, then $F$ is a linear transformation of the base field, ie. multiplication by a constant $c$"? I don't think I follow the logic.
Follow up questions: 1. if the matrix is singular, then the determinant is zero, but having a zero determinant doesn't necessarily imply that the rank stays the same right? So can $F$ still change the matrix rank in this case? 2. what about the case where the matrix is non-singular?

I expanded the logic a bit. I do not understand your follow-up questions because the premise was that the function would preserve rank, so we should not distinguish between functions $F$ that apply only to singular matrices and other functions that apply only to regular matrices. Re: 1, note that for a square matrix, having determinant 0 is equivalent to the rank being less than the size of the matrix.

Hi @Lieven I am still learning so apologies if my questions sound silly/obvious, but how does $F(ax)/F(a) = F(bx)/F(b)$ imply that $F$ is a multiplication by a constant $c$? Is this from a well known theorem? And would $F(x) = k$ for a constant $k$ be a counter example to this?

For 1. what I mean is this:
$$Y = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$Z = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
Both matrices $Y$ and $Z$ have determinant $0$ but different ranks. We can construct a function $F(x)$ that maps elements from matrix $Y$ to matrix $Z$. Just because $det(F(Y))=0$ and $det(F(Z))=0$ doesn't mean that $F(x)$ preserves matrix rank right? Don't we need a stronger statement beyond showing $det(F(Y))=det(F(Z))$ i.e. $F(a)F(bx) - F(ax)F(b) = 0$?

For 2. I misread your solution but I understand it now and found the answer, so apologies, you can ignore that second question!

Sure, two singular square matrices of the same size can have different rank. But I am reasoning in the opposite direction: IF such a function preserves rank, THEN it must map singular matrices to singular matrices (because a singular matrix always has rank strictly less than $n,$ while a regular matrix always has rank $n$).

After re-reading your response, I think I understand now -- "if the function exists, then it must satisfy $F(ax)/F(a)=F(bx)/F(b)$". However, it is still not clear to me how this necessarily implies that "if the function exists, then $F$ must be a multiplication by a constant $c$". The link doesn't seem obvious to me... There are many other functions that satisfy this equality, e.g. $F(x) = k$ for some constant $k$, or $F(x) = |x|$, possibly many others as well. How do we rule out all of these other functions and only have the "multiplication by a constant $c$" functions remain?

Thanks for insisting. You have made me realize that the situation is slightly more complicated in dimension 2, and requires additional arguments in higher dimensions. I have adapted my answer accordingly.

Thank you @Lievan that was a wonderful read!
